# Column sum of adjoint of a matrix.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, linear-algebra, matrices

Suppose we have a symmetric square matrix $A$. Let adj$(A)$ be the adjoint of A.

> Do we have any result which gives us the column sum of any column of adj$(A)$ in terms of known terms with respect to the matrix $A$, say for example $\det (A)$.

Ref: Adjoint: [Adjoint](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjugate_matrix)

Comment: @user When you say "adjoint", are you referring to the [classical adjoint](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjugate_matrix) (more typically called the adjugate) or the [Hermitian adjoint](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hermitian_adjoint)?

Comment: @BenGrossmann I am referring to classical adjoint.

Answer (score 0):

The column sum of $\operatorname{adj}(A)$, when written out, can be identified as the [Laplace expansion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_expansion) of a determinant. For instance, the sum of the first column of $\operatorname{adj}(A)$ is the determinant of the matrix
$$
\sum_i\operatorname{adj}(A)_{i1} = \det\pmatrix{1 & 1 & \cdots & 1\\
a_{21} & a_{22} & \cdots & a_{2n}\\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots\\
a_{n1} & a_{n2} & \cdots & a_{nn}}.
$$
Similarly, the $k$th column sum can be written as the determinant of $A$ with each entry of the $k$th row replaced with a $1$.